# Can docker "instance" run totally in ram?

Tags: docker

I would like to power a docker instance in ram... totally inside ram... using tmpfs

Can it be done?

I'm not sure how docker uses filesystems as I'm too used to using kvm and xen, they both need to set up a default size before it can be used.

So how does "docker fs" work?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done. If you mount /var/lib/docker on a tmpfs, Docker can use other storage backends, like OverlayFS, on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

Docker uses what it calls a "Union File System", made up of multiple read-only layers with a copy-on-write layer on top (see http://docs.docker.com/terms/layer/). It can use one of several storage drivers for this (in order of preference): AUFS, BTRFS, devicemapper, overlayfs or VFS. Because of this, no, I don't think you will be able to use tmpfs.

More information at https://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/09/30/overview-storage-scalability-docker/

Comment: I have read. Can't wrap my head around this unionfs. Mind if I ask if this unionfs is expandable? How to check if docker is using within limits of the underlying fs? So where does this unionfs reside currently and how big is it?

Comment: i finished reading a few docker stuff. The "disk image" dynamically grows but does not shrink with docker. Am i right?

Comment: @stashfree Yes, it doesn't shrink. That's why you will see people going to great lengths in Dockerfiles to avoid adding unnecessary files. You can have a look in /var/lib/docker to see where Docker keeps things. It's all just directories and files on your host.

Comment: not bad! thanks Adrian. Tried out docker for an hour, very impressed with its low resource usage. Know it's great for development env. Wonder if it's really ready for production use.